# Get names of all function decorators

Tags: python, python-3.x

I would like to apply a decorator to all methods of a class programmatically. With a condition that if a certain decorator already exists, skip adding the decorator to that method.

I have something like this code, but I can't figure out the API that would tell me what other decorators may already exist on the method. In my case I want to skip adding `cacheable` decorator for certain methods which have the `non_cacheable` decorator on them

```
def cacheable():
     def decorate(cls):
        for name, fn in inspect.getmembers(cls, inspect.ismethod):
            setattr(cls, name, decorator(fn))
        return cls
    return decorate

@cacheable
class C(object):
    
    @not_cacheable
    def method_1(self): pass

    def method_2(self, x): pass
    ...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding an attribute:

```
def not_cachable(func):
    func._cache = False
    return func
```

Then check the attribute in your `cacheable` decorator.

That's how many of the functions in the standard library work, for example `@abstractmethod`.